# Reset var from ViewController inside the UITableCell class with prepareForReuse function

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView that has some cells. Those cells have numbers and I am totalling all those numbers up and then displaying the total (grandTotal).

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       grandTotal = 0.00
}
```

This is a simplified version of the app, i'm using CoreData to store the values.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       grandTotal! += grandTotal + 100
}
```

The issue that grandTotal is not reset back to 0.00 each time cellForRowAt is called. I have a custom UITableViewCell with this function.

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    print("recalculate totals!!!!!!!")
}
```

After the UITableView loads, and displays all the data correctly, if the user swipes up, it triggers the cellForRowAt function, and then recalculates the grandTotal, not by starting from 0.00, but what the total was after the tableView loaded.

I would like to set the grandTotal var back to 0.00 in the perpareForReuse function, but not sure how to again access to the grandTotal var from the custom cell class.

The grandTotal var is created inside my ViewController class.

**** EDIT ****

I have an app that keeps track of loans. So you create a person you want to add to your list. That person can have multiple loans attached to them. Some are money you lent (positive numbers), why others are money you borrowed (negative numbers). The TableView displays all the persons in your app. Each cell also adds up the all the loans for each person and either displays a positive or negative number for that person. What I am trying to do is then add up all the totals for each person and display that as a Grand Total. I got this working, but if I swipe up or down on the tableview, it re-calculcates my totals, and instead of starting from 0, it uses the current numbers.

It seems that it was suggested that I shouldn't be doing calculations in the cellForRowAt function, I'm just not sure how I would go about it, as I'm using the cell indexPath to pull the person data out of CoreData.

```
let person = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects![indexPath.row]
```

Again it seems if I could figure out a way to set grandTotal back to 0 each time the prepareForReuse func is called that might work. I'm just not sure how to access that var inside the ViewController

I tried something like this:

```
let viewController:ViewController = ViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    print("\(String(describing: viewController.oweTotal)) owe total from perpare")  --> nil
    print("\(String(describing: viewController.owedTotal)) owed total from perpare")  --> nil
```

But I think I'm just creating a new VC instead of referencing the one that already exists.

Comment: You shouldn't do calculations inside `cellForRowAt` for precisely this reason. You should pass your prepared data to your table view and make your calculations based on your data source.

Comment: Is your "grand total" supposed to be the total for just the cells that are currently visible on screen? As David says in his comment, you should not be doing calculations in cellForRowAt. The table view could ask for the same cell more than once, ask for cells out of order, etc. If you tell us what you're trying to do we might be able to offer suggestions on how to accomplish it.

Comment: I'll edit the question to give more detail.

Comment: @Duncan C, does that help you understand what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell what exactly is going on here from the sample code.

When a cell is dequeued "Taken off the View" it is "recycled". When you swipe up, what is happening is the recycled cell is being configured in the cellForRowAt... func.

From the code shown, for this example, you could calculate the "Grand Total" by keeping track of the largest "IndexPath" on the table view

```
max = max(max,indexPath.row)
```

with max being a var on the class init at 0